# codeigniter - simple database insert failing without errors

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I'm running a codeigniter application, and i can't get this simple insert to work well.

```
if(!$this->db->insert('myTable',$entry)){
    $p3 = 0;
}else{
    echo $this->db->last_query();
    var_dump($this->db->_error_message());
}
```

the debug in the "else" clause always show me an empty string for error message, and  if i test the last_query in phpmyadmin, the insert work well.

But the insert isn't happening when i normally run the app, even if the "else" is launched, implying the request succeed.

any clue ?

UPDATE : exemple of $entry array :

```
$entry = array(
    'id' => '',
    'id_devis' => $current[0]->id,
    'metier' => $_POST[$i+1 . '_create_metier'],
    'days' => $_POST[$i+1 . '_create_daycount'],
    'price' => $_POST[$i+1 . '_create_price'],
    'cr_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'user' => ''
);
```

$current is an extract of another table (using $this->db->get), and all the datas are fine, since i can insert them through the echo of last_query()

Comment: Can you print the $entry array in your app, before executing the query and post it here?

Comment: Insert `echo $this->db->last_query();` before `}else{` and see what will be the output when inserting, there may be some strange situation when silently failing to insert there were no obvious errors from MySQL driver.

Comment: id is the primary key of the table.

I just tried to put the echo in the 'if' statement, only "else" is running

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

before the line with the insert. You should see an error message.

My guess is that you try to insert an illegal value for id. Possible reasons:
- It should not be empty.
- It can not be a string (ie. if the type is an integer)

Most of the time an id in the database is of type int and is an auto-increment field. If so, you should not try to insert an id. It will be created for you.

Comment: I still don't get an error message with error reporting enabled.

I removed the 'id' field from the array since it seems to be useless, and the query returned by last_query still works.

You're right about the auto_increment int field, but none of those points are causing the bug, that's why i don't understand

-my php logs are cleans, and the query returned by last_query works fine in phpmyadmin, so logically it's not a php bug, nor a mysql bug. Weird !

Answer (score 1):

Just found out the issue, there wasn't. a script was deleting the line i just inserted further in the code, the insert was successful. Thanks for your answers all

Comment: omg! thank you! this was exactly what was happening to me too! spent 2 hours debugging, and luckily came across this comment.